# Can someone tell me why my script is wrong

Tags: lua, roblox

SO my Anti godmode exploit script is incorrect. I need a fix for it so people can go in god mode.

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)

end)

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    if plr and plr:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then

    end
end)
```

Finds player's humanoid and local it :)

'end' is a end from if statement.

```
    end
end
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    if plr and plr:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        if plr:FindFirstChild("Humanoid").Health == 100 then
            print(plr.Character.Name.." is a good player he didn't exploits :)")
        else
            plr:Kick("You have been banned by hacking into god mode >:(")
        end
    end
end)
```

Comment: Please re-format your code and explain whats going wrong. What do you expect to happen and what is exactly happening ? Do you get errors?

Comment: Checking to make sure a `Humanoid`'s health is exactly 100 is a bad idea. What happens in the case where a non-exploiter is below full health? Based on the if-then conditional you have written, that player would still be kicked. Also, `Humanoid` is a member of a player's character model, not the `Player` object.

Comment: All you need to do to allow God Mode is add extra checks before `plr:Kick()` so that people can acceptably not have 100 health. So you should ask yourself how do you want to allow people to get God Mode? Do they need to join a specific group? Do they need to buy a Game Pass? Do they need to enter a secret password? When you know, you should update your question based on khoekman's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, PlayerAdded gets the player instance, and you're attempting to find a Humanoid instance that will never exist under the Player, as its a descendant of the character object.

Your code should be...

```lua
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr) -- Grab the player instance on join
    plr.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character) -- Grab the character once it loads
        character:WaitForChild("Humanoid") -- Wait for the humanoid object
        if character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid").Health <= 100 then
            print(plr.Name.." is a good player he didn't exploits :)")
        else
            plr:Kick("You have been banned by hacking into god mode >:(")
        end
    end)
end)
```

Now, this is how you would fix YOUR code, but realistically, this isn't a good method to detect exploiters using godmode, as this method would only check once. I recommend doing some kind of loop such as...

```lua
while wait(1) do
    if character.Humanoid.Health > 100 then
        plr:Kick("Invalid health")
    end
end
```